# why this guard don't throw exception?

Tags: erlang

Consider the following code:

```
    -module(abc).
    -export([f/1]).
    f(X) when (X==0) or (1/X>2) -> X+100;
    f(X) ->X.
```

and abc:f(0). get result 0 , but why 1/X don't throw exception ??

Comment: The [Erlang comments](http://www.erlang.org/eeps/eep-0014.html) say:
_"You are advised never to use the 'and' and 'or' operators and to avoid 'andalso' and 'orelse' whenever ',' and ';' will do what you need."_ (But fails to give a reason.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Guard Sequences](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id79432) section of the erlang documentation says:

> If an arithmetic expression, a boolean expression, a short-circuit expression, or a call to a guard BIF fails (because of invalid arguments), the entire guard fails. If the guard was part of a guard sequence, the next guard in the sequence (that is, the guard following the next semicolon) will be evaluated.

In other words, exceptions in guards are treated as if the guard returned false without raising the exception. The evaluation of guards is slightly different than that of normal erlang expressions.

When you call `abc:f(0)`, the expression `(0==0) or (1/0>2)` is evaluated. This expression "fails" because of division by zero so the guard does not match and the next clause is evaluated to give the answer of `0`.

If you want this case to return `100` you have two options: use a guard sequence or use short circuit boolean operators. These would be

```
f(X) when X==0; 1/X>2 -> X + 100;
f(X) -> X.
```

and

```
f(X) when X==0 orelse 1/X>2 -> X + 100;
f(X) -> X.
```

respectively. Both ways of writing it will evaluate `X==0` as a separate exception and not execute `1/X>2` if the result is true.

Comment: but how the guard treats 1/X>2, when X=0 ,why don't throw arithmetic exception??

Comment: because the first guard returns true, and its an `OR` evaluation, then, it doesn't bother with the second guard - i guess ?

Comment: @Muzaaya Joshua:No,what you say is orelse

Comment: The evaluation of guards should not have any side effects, just like pattern matching. The arithmetic exception you seek is caught and converted to a 'false' value to hide the side effect.

Answer (score 4):

See [here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id79432) for the documentation. To nit-pick and be precise:

A guard consists of a sequence of *tests*, not expressions, and a *test* will either succeed or fail, if there is an error in a test it will not generate an exception it will just fail.

In a guard you can have a *guard sequence* which is a sequence of guards separated by `;`, if one of the guards succeeds then the whole guard sequence succeeds. So `;` separates alternate guards.

In a guard can have a sequence of guard tests separated by `,`, all the tests in a guard must succeed for the whole guard to succeed. So a most general guard will be:

```
f(...) when <test11>, <test12> ; <test21>, <test22> ; ... ->
```

So what about boolean operators and how do they relate to tests, `,` and `;`? It is perfectly legal to use boolean operators in guard tests and they behave as expected, ***BUT*** they are **not** the same as using `,` and `;`. Especially with respect to failure. So the boolean expression `<test11> and <test12>` is just **one** test and not a sequence of two. More importantly `<test11> or test<21>` (or using `orelse`) is still one guard test not a sequence of two guards. So an error in `<test11>` will fail the whole guard. Whereas with `<test11> ; < test21>` an error in `<test11>` will fail that guard test and the alternate guard `<test21>` will be tried.

That is the reason behind the advice in the comment mentioned by @ShiDoiSi. You can use either but be aware of what they mean and how they behave. And **remember**: *guards consist of tests not expressions*.

P.S. Some history as to why it is like this. It is very simple really: we had guards long before we had boolean operators so when we finally did get boolean operators the semantics of guards was already well defined and it was too late to change. While allowing boolean expressions in guards allows you to write more precise guards it does tend to hide the true nature of guards.